# Why italic font is not working

Tags: html, css, fonts

I am learning CSS. I tried to make some text italic. But the text are not going italic. Where is the problem?

```css
.bold {
  font-weight: bold;
}

.italic {
  font-weight: italic;
}
```

```html
<p>This is some text</p>

<p class="bold">This is some bold text</p>

<p class="italic">This is some italic text</p>
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can't set italics using a CSS command called `font-weight`.

Try using [`font-style: italic`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/font-style) instead.

```css
.bold {
  font-weight: bold;
}

.italic {
  font-style: italic;
}
```

```html
<p>This is some text</p>

<p class="bold">This is some bold text</p>

<p class="italic">This is some italic text</p>
```

Answer (score 3):

Italic isn't a font **weight** (which determines how bold the text is). It's [a `font-style`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/font-style)

Answer (score 3):

Use `font-style: italic;` instead.

`font-weight` is responsible for boldness, and uses number (100, 200, 300,..., 900) to set it; "bold" is just a special value there.

Answer (score 3):

`italic` is a [`font-style`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/font-style) property, not font weight:

```
.italic{
font-style:italic;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You Have Given Wrong Property for ***ITALIC***,Try This property and give same value

```
.italic{
font-style:italic;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

that's wrong

try this:

```
.italic{font-style:italic;}
```